# How to solve $(z-1)^n=(z+1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, fractions, roots-of-unity

I have problem with this equation because when I put
$\left(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^n=1$ I find solutions different than when I put $\left(\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^n=1$
So which one should I use ?
For first one -icot(kπ/5) and icot(kπ/5) for the second one

Comment: What solutions do you have for both equations ?

Comment: There is a "solution at infinity" which may be confusing the issue.

Comment: For first one -icot(kπ/5) and icot(kπ/5) for the second one

Comment: Which solution is right ?

Answer (score 2):

The approaches agree. Whether you argue$$\frac{z+1}{z-1}=e^{2\pi ik/n},\,k\in\Bbb Z\implies z=\frac{e^{2\pi ik/n}+1}{e^{2\pi ik/n}-1}=-i\cot\frac{\pi k}{n}$$or$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=e^{2\pi il/n},\,l\in\Bbb Z\implies\frac{z+1}{z-1}=e^{2\pi ik/n},\,k=-l,$$from which we can continue with the above logic, the solution sets are the same.

Comment: Can you explain more pleas

Comment: @BadrEddine Distinct functions $f,\,g$ can achieve $\{f(k)|k\in\Bbb Z\}=\{g(l)|l\in\Bbb Z\}$; it's just giving a set two different parameterizations.